# Write an = inside QuasiQuotes

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

How do I write a `=` inside a QuasiQuote expression?

```
[uri|https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email|]
```

Currently I get

```
example/Facebook/test.hs:56:83: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Comment: Make sure you actually have the `QuasiQuotes` extension turned on.

Comment: head -> desk - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the correct language extension for QuasiQuotes to work. In source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
```

In GHCI:

```
:set -XQuasiQuotes
```